# Next.js Static Site Generation Issue: searchParams.toJSON Error During Build

Tags: next.js, deployment, build, next.js13

I'm encountering a persistent issue with building a Next.js application for static deployment on Hostinger cloud hosting. The build process fails with the following error:

```
[Error]: Page with `dynamic = "error"` couldn't be rendered statically because it used `searchParams.toJSON`.
```

I've thoroughly reviewed my codebase and can confirm that I'm not using searchParams.toJSON anywhere in my application. The primary goal is to deploy a static version due to hosting constraints.

Here are some key details:

I'm using Next.js for static site generation.

The application has NO dynamic routes and does not use searchParams.toJSON.

I use a significant number of fetch requests to external APIs.

The application utilizes Redux for state management.

React context is employed for global state.

The app is complex, involving various components, pages, and interactions.

I'm attempting to deploy on Hostinger cloud hosting.

I've tried various troubleshooting steps, including adjusting the request function and reviewing dependencies, but the issue persists. I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this error and successfully build the static pages for deployment.

Here are my main questions:

Could the usage of fetch requests, Redux, or React context be causing conflicts with static site generation?

Are there specific considerations or adjustments needed for static generation when using fetch, Redux, or React context?

I appreciate any insights, guidance, or suggestions from the community to help resolve this issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Solution Found: Issue with 'use client' in Next.js Pages

I'm writing to share the solution I found to a problem that I've been grappling with for the past two days regarding Next.js static site generation. The error I encountered during the build process was:
"[Error]: Page with dynamic = "error" couldn't be rendered statically because it used searchParams.toJSON."

After extensive investigation, I discovered that the presence of 'use client' at the top of the page.js components was causing this error. The key takeaway is that in Next.js pages, components should not have 'use client' at the top. Removing this line resolved the issue for me.

Over the course of two days, I sought assistance from various sources, including AI, forums, and exhaustive Google searches. Despite the efforts, the breakthrough came during an 8-hour session where I meticulously examined each component. I systematically moved them to a new Next.js app, running builds after adding each one. This process allowed me to isolate the problematic line of code.

I'm sharing this experience to save time for others who might encounter a similar issue. If you're facing the mentioned error during Next.js static site generation, thoroughly check your components for the presence of 'use client' at the top. Omitting this line in pages can prevent the error and enable successful static site generation.